# inotify or similar on centos

Tags: centos, inotify

I need to get alerted when a new directory or sub directory is created within the root directory that I am monitoring. The alert has to be triggered to a PHP file. How do I do this on CentOS? Is inotify the best route to take? I just need to know when a new directory is created and the location. So I am looking for the simplest of ideas to do this.

- I have full control of the server
- I just need to monitor creation of a directory
- Alerts have to be sent to a PHP file (directly or indirectly)

Please send through any ideas you might have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the EPEL repo to your CentOS host there is an "incron" package available which works with inotify to do what you're looking to do.  Here's the docs: http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=doc&lang=en

Comment: `incron` won't work recursively though. `inotifywatch` from inotify-tools will.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 6.3 has `inotifywait` built in.

Comment: You might consider adding more detail to your answer. How long has it been in CentOS?